# Can not find sqlite localstorage file on Android device (motorola tc 55)

Tags: android, sqlite, synchronization, sencha-touch

Lately I am testing a synchronization framework, called [sqlite-sync.com](http://sqlite-sync.com/).
It runs smoothly, the only question for me so far is that, I **can not find where the Android app stores the local sqlite file**.
I noticed the android client is using sencha touch framework, the underlying proxy for data storage is called "sqlitestorageproxy".
I checked, my **data/data folder is empty**.
I am using Motorola Tc55.
Code responsible for opening database is like this:

```
      if (!window.openDatabase) {
           alert('Error creating database.');
        } else {
         this.dbConn = openDatabase(shortName, version, displayName, maxSize);
      }
```

Please help me find the file. THank you.

Comment: How you checked the /data/data/ directory

Answer (score 0):

1. OK. I found the answer. The device was rooted and I was using "root
   browser" app the check the data/data folder, it says it's empty.
2. However it was misleading, because when I logged in from command
   line    using adb, it says "permission denied".

   Then I realized that I have to do the following to see and copy the content of my data folder:

adb shell "run-as com.sqlitesync.demo ls -l /data/data/com.sqlitesync.demo/app_database"

adb shell "run-as com.sqlitesync.demo chmod 666 /data/data/com.sqlitesync.demo/app_database/Databases.db"

adb pull /data/data/app_database/Databases.db C:\Users\Public

adb shell "run-as com.sqlitesync.demo chmod 600 /data/data/com.sqlitesync.demo/app_database/Databases.db"